# Prove the following: suppose H has index p and K has index q, where p and q are distinct primes. Then the index of H∩K is a multiple of pq

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

For this problem, assume $G$ is a finite group and that $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$. Also, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then the index of $H$ can be expressed as $(G:H)=ord(G)/ord(H).$

I've posted my proof below; however, I'm considering this to be a rough draft and am getting an intuitive hunch that my proof is wrong. As a result, I'd be grateful for any feedback.  Thanks.

Proof(Draft/Brainstorm)

Suppose $H$ has index $p$ and $K$ has index $q$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. Then $p=\text{ord}(G)/\text{ord}(H)$ or $\text{ord}(G)=p(\text{ord}(H)),$ so $\text{ord}(G)$ is a multiple of $p$. Similarly, $\text{ord}(G)=q(\text{ord}(K))$, so $\text{ord}(G)$ is a multiple of $q$. Since $\text{ord}(G)$ is a multiple of $p$ and $q$, then $\text{ord}(G)$ is also a multiple of $\text{lcm}(p,q).$ Since $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then $\text{lcm}(p,q)$ equals $pq$, and so $\text{ord}(G)$ is a multiple of $pq$.  Now, $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $G$, and via Lagrange's Theorem, $\text{ord}(G)$ is a multiple of $\text{ord}(H\cap K).$  Consequently, since $\text{ord}(G)$ is a multiple of $pq$ and $\text{ord}(H\cap K)$, then $\text{ord}(G)=\text{ord}(H\cap K)pq$ or $$pq=\frac{\text{ord}(G)}{\text{ord}(H\cap K)}=(G:(H\cap K)).$$  Hence, the index of $(H\cap K)$ is a multiple of $pq$.

Comment: Hint: $[G:H \cap K]=[G:H][H:H \cap K]$ (why?)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, Thomas Rasberry.  Unfortunately, abstract and theoretical math doesn't come easily to me. With that said, besides seeing that [G:H∩K]=(ord(G)/ord(H))*(ord(H)/ord(H∩K))=ord(G)/ord(H∩K), I can't see anything else.  Could you elaborate further please? Thanks

Comment: Let $H/(H\cap K)=\{x(H\cap K):x\in H\}$ be the family of left cosets of $H$ over $H\cap K.$ ..And let $G/H=\{y_nH: 1\leq n\leq p\}. $  For $1\leq i<j\leq p$ and for $x,x'\in H$ with $x(H\cap K)\ne x'(H\cap K)$ we have $y_ix(H\cap K)\ne y_jx'(H\cap K).$ ....(Else $x'^{-1}y_j^{-1}y_ix\in$ $ (H\cap K)$ $\subset H,$ with $x,x'\in H,$ but then $y_j^{-1}y_i\in H$)....  So  $G/(H\cap K)=\cup_{i=1}^p\{y_i S: S\in H/(H\cap K\}$ has $(p)(H:H\cap K)$ members.

Answer (score 3):

First, here are several things about your proof:

1. The fact that $|G|$ is a multiple of $pq$ and $|H\cap K|$ follows directly from Lagrange's theorem, and is irrelevant for this problem
2. You cannot conclude that $|G|=|H\cap K|pq$ simply from the fact that $|H\cap K|$ and $pq$ divide $|G|$, and in fact this is not necessarily the case. As an example, consider $G=S_3\times \mu_2$, with $\mu_2$ the cyclic group of order $2$, and the two subgroups $H=S_3$ and $$K=\{((12),0),((12),1),((1),0),((1),1)\},$$ where $[G:H]=2$ and $[G:K]=3$.

This is in fact very simple if you first show the following fact:

If $G\geq H\geq K$, then $[G:K]=[G:H][H:K],$

(where here $[G:K]$ is the index of $K$ in $G$). Hope this helps.